# Android studio: Build -> Build APK(s) vs Run app (play button)

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, unsatisfiedlinkerror, android-native-library

I'm new to Android Studio and I would like to know the difference between the APK generated using Build -> Build APK(s) and the one using the 'play' button (Ctrl+F5).

The problem is the following: I'm using some native libraries and when debugging with Ctrl+F5 (the play button) I get an UnsatisfiedLinkError because the library is not found. Indeed if I open the APK (Build ->Analyze APK) I see there is no 'lib' folder so no .so lib.

However when I Build -> Build APK(s) and then analyze this new APK I can see the 'lib' folder with all the .so libs. Then if I copy this APK inside my phone and install the app, everything works fine (I use Native Libs Monitor and it recognizes the native libs inside).

Of course I cannot do this everytime so I'm looking for the differences so that I can understand why the libs are not created inside the apk in the fist case.

Answer (score 1):

The simple explanation is that the build .apk makes your project generate all the code into one file (.apk) and then it can be opened and installed on Android.
If run which is like the 'play button' runs your project without you needing to install the .apk file first and of course this makes it easier for you as a developer.

if there is an error problem, you should attach the error message to your question and it is better if you attach it in the form of a screenshot.

Comment: Ok i get it. Because at first I thought it was release/debug build but it made no sense. Anyway now I solved the problem by adding 
ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi'
        } 
inside defaultConfig in the build.gradle. This should force the apk manager to put the lib folder inside but I'm not 100% sure how it works. Still, it works so I wont complain. Thanks